# How to change generated activity title?

Tags: android, zxing, titlebar

I have created a simple bar code generator using XZing library.

to do it I used a code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "UPC_A");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "12345678901");
startActivity(intent);
```

I need to get rid of the title in this activity(grey bar in top of activity) ! Could you tell me how to do it ?
[Image](http://www.smrw.lodz.pl/~adamt/Screenshot.png)

Answer (score 0):

`this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

before the `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`in the Activity where you want to remove the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the title bar of someone else activity. If you have the source then you can used the above suggestion.